# Angular 2 URL Re-Writing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular2-routing

I am new in Angular 2. I am working on project where i have a requirement like ' https://www.zomato.com/ ' for url re-writing. means in zomato when we select city it will show city in url like ' https://www.zomato.com/indore ' and when we select any restaurant the url will be like 'https://www.zomato.com/indore/square-sayaji-hotel-vijay-nagar' (url contains hotel name + address with dash). and in my site i am currently doing this ' http://fw.proaspire.com/restaurant-details?id=1 '

i need How can i implement it ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: I want to know how can i implement this ?

Comment: url rewriting has nothing to do with angular....

Answer (score 0):

You need to write url rewrites in .htaccess if you are using apache.

Comment: i am using IIS web server. so will i need to write in web.config ?